# When I connect to an Account using the Drive API, I get an email with Appname of 'QuickStart'

Tags: google-api

I have recently setup an account in Google APIs and Services. In this account I enabled Google Drive integration. In the Drive UI Integration section, I have setup the Application Name as per this screenshot: https://www.screencast.com/t/5VphcOkfAXyN

In the Credentials section which I setup for this application, I also entered my application name: https://www.screencast.com/t/3XudlhbE

When I connect to my account via OpenAuth, I get a confirmation email to the connected account, from Google, which tells me that 'Quickstart connected to your Google Account'. I am expecting that the email would tell me 'My App Name connected to your Google Account': https://www.screencast.com/t/fmSXswXS

I have searched through my Google Account settings but I can't find anywhere where it says 'Quickstart'. What do I need to do in order to ensure that my actual app name is the one that appears on the confirmation email, and in the 'Apps with access to your account' permissions page (https://www.screencast.com/t/hcHSkDr5)?

Here is my FlowMetadata as requested in the comments:

```
public class GoogleDriveAppFlowMetadata : FlowMetadata
{
    private static readonly IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
        new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
        {
            ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
            {
                ClientId = AppConfig.CloudStorage.Google.Drive.ClientId,
                ClientSecret = AppConfig.CloudStorage.Google.Drive.ClientSecret,
            },
            Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
            DataStore = new GoogleDriveDataStore(),
        });

    public override string AuthCallback
    {
        get { return @"/GoogleDriveAuthCallback/IndexAsync"; }
    }

    public override string GetUserId(Controller controller)
    {
        if (controller.HttpContext.Session[SessionConstants.CloudStorageAccount] == null)
            throw new Exception("CloudStorageAccount was not populated!");

        CloudStorageDto cs = (CloudStorageDto)controller.HttpContext.Session[SessionConstants.CloudStorageAccount];
        return $"{controller.User.GetSessionToken()}_{cs.Id}";
    }

    public override IAuthorizationCodeFlow Flow
    {
        get { return flow; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: @DaImTo thanks for your comment but I don't understand why you want to see my code? My application name is not defined anywhere in the code... Just to clarify, the confirmation email I am getting is from Google, not from my system.

Comment: I can not test your application without seeing your code.   The fact of the matter is that when you are requesting authncation the email you get is for the application that sent the request.   So either you have been using someone elses client id and get their name or you have run someones sample project that contains their client id.   What you are saying should not happen.  So before i send an email to google stating they have a major issue i want to see a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from you proving it.  :)

Comment: @DaImTo, I've got my code from https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc and adpated it. I definitely haven't copied the client Id and secret from anywhere else. I've just been and fetched the client id and secret and re-encrypted them (I store them encrypted), and then removed the authorisation from my account, and then re-authorised. I received a confirmation email with the same 'Quickstart' app name. I'll post some code.

Comment: I have found more settings in the OAuth Consent Screen tab - will test this and write as an answer if this fixes things: https://www.screencast.com/t/cI4lZKmNWeKp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the setting in the OAuth Consent Screen tab - this is the one that I needed: https://screencast.com/t/cI4lZKmNWeKp